# Generalizing UI element relationships in a single iOS view

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, interface-builder

I am creating a calculator view that uses sliders to set textbox values. Each textbox has a slider that corresponds to it. The code for updating textbox values is as follows:

```
- (void) updateAlphaTextField:(id)sender 
{
    int value = [alphaSlider value];

    NSString *stringValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",value];

    [alphaTextField setText:stringValue];    
}
```

However I have about 20 textboxes (and 20 corresponding sliders) that I would like to demonstrate this behavior and I don't want to write 20 of these update functions.

Is there a function that I can write that could watch all the sliders and update a corresponding textbox with the right value? If so, how do I make my IB connections to get it to work? (The above function required 1 IB connection to be made)

Or even better is there a Cocoa Touch function that would allow me to do this easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put tags in your `UITextFields` and `UISliders`. For instance: UITextField 1, would have `tag` 1 and the `UISlider` 1, would also have `tag` 1. Then, create an IBOutlet collection with all your `UITextField`s. You can use this to help you out:

http://www.bobmccune.com/2011/01/31/using-ios-4s-iboutletcollection/

In your function do this:

```
- (void) updateAlphaTextField:(id)sender 
{
    int value = [alphaSlider value];

    NSString *stringValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",value];

    UISlider *senderSlider = (UISlider*)sender;

    for(UITextField *textField in textFieldCollection){
       if(textField.tag==senderSlider.tag){
           [textField setText:stringValue];   
       }
    }
```

}

Comment: I get an "property tag not found on object type strong id" error, is there a way to identify the slider using the id?

Comment: I actually worked around the issue, and corrected your answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle all of your UISlider changes in your view controller. To map a slider to a specific text field, set on both the same `tag` property. Then you can enumerate all your text fields and check, wether the `tag` property is equal.

```
[mySlider1 addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[mySlider2 addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

And in your `sliderValueChanged:` method:

```
for (UITextField *textField in allMyTextFields) {
    if (sender.tag == textField.tag) {
        [textField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", value]];
    }
}
```

Comment: is allMyTextFields a built in variable or do I need to define it? I did not set the view up programmatically.

Comment: In my opinion the best option is with a IBOutlet Collection.

Comment: @AndrewBarinov You have to define the variable yourself. I didn't know of the IBOutlet collection, which Jacky Boy mentions, but this looks good to me.